# java-is this good programming?

Tags: java

```
package com.mohamadibrah;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(returnAverage(printNumbers(enterNumbers()))); // 10
    }


    public static double returnAverage(double[] array){
        double result=0;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            result += array[i];
        }
        System.out.println("the average is:");
        return (double)result/(array.length);
    }


    public static double[] enterNumbers(){
        System.out.println("please enter the number of values:");
        int sca = sc.nextInt();
        double[] myAverage = new double[sca];
        System.out.println("please enter the numbers:");
        for(int i=0;i<myAverage.length;i++){
            double input = sc.nextDouble();
            myAverage[i] = input;
        }
        return myAverage;
    }

    public static double[] printNumbers(double[] array1){
        System.out.println("your numbers are:");
        double[] array2 = new double[array1.length];
        for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("the number "+i+" is:"+array1[i]);
            array2[i] = array1[i];
        }
        return array2;
    }
}
```

the one with the "10" in the comment

is it good programming to stack multiple methods together if everything is working fine? or is it better to keep them separated as much as possible

Comment: If it works, this is probably more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suggest you use the code analysis in your IDE to give you suggestions on how you could have done it differently (and use the code formatter)

Comment: `returnAverage` returns the average, it shouldn't print anything.

Comment: considering this is Java, not very OOP

Answer (score 1):

The issues here are **debuggability** and **readability**.

---

**Debuggability**:

When you debug such a code, it can get pretty tricky to inspect each inner method return value.

---

**Readability**:

Asside from it being hard to follow, since the reader needs to read the code from the inside out, you miss the chance to give a meaningful name to a variable that holds the inner method return value, thus explaining to the reader what it is.

---

Consider the following alternate code with the above points in mind:

```
List<Double> userChosenNumbers = enterNumbers();
Double average = returnAverage(userChosenNumbers);
System.out.println(average);
```